# How to use regular expression(/^ $/i) of MongoDB in go?

Tags: regex, mongodb, go

MongoDB Query

```
db.getCollection('name').count({"nickname": /^nickname$/i})
```

==> In this case, I want to know how to use MongoDB Query in Golang

(It doesn't work if something like this)

```
nickname := "nickname"
db.GetCollection("name").CountDocuments(
        context.Background(),
        bson.M{"nickname": "/^" + nickname + "$/i"},
)
```

Comment: https://learningprogramming.net/golang/golang-and-mongodb/use-regex-in-golang-and-mongodb/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for your reply. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @AkashPatel I got a hint from your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you considered using [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/#collation) to get case-insensitivity instead of regex so an index can be used more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

```
nickname := "nickname"
db.GetCollection("name").CountDocuments(
        context.Background(),
        bson.M{"nickname": primitive.Regex{
            Pattern: "^" + nickname + "$",
            Options: "i",
        }},
)
```